# Decompile / recompile my own apk

Tags: android

I followed this tutorial: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2251719 
I coded a typical hello world application, with a toast "some text here".
Then i extracted the .apk file from the device, decompiled it as shown in the turorial, and edited the toast in "some modified text here".
Once recompiled the .apk file, and installed back on the device, the toast still display the old "some text here"...
Someone can tell me where i'm wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you install you apk using `adb install`? If so, use the flag `-r`

Answer (score 0):

Damn, my bad ... i was a little bit inattentive ... in that guide, at point "k - now sign the apk" i used the original .apk file instead of the one inside the /myapk folder created at point "j".
 now all works fine, i'm sorry for my distraction!